# Shortcut to colllaspe/fold all methods in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts, folding

I'm mainly working on PyCharm, and lot of times, I come into a situation where it would be much better if I can collapse/fold all method bodies, and leave their names only.

The picture below is the the result I want, but I can't find the shortcut to do this thing. If you know any, let me know.

[image: c]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can collapse the code as shown in the screenshot going to `Code` `>` `Folding` `>` `Expand All to Level` `>` `1` or using the keyboard shortcut  <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + NumPad *, 1</kbd>.

The level is absolute relative to the module level. If you have nested methods or classes you can select them individually an use the equivalent `Expand to Level` instead of `Expand All to Level`.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

When your keyboard doesn't have Numpad button.
You can

- Expand using Ctrl, Shift and + buttons together
- Collapse using Ctrl, Shift and - buttons together

Answer (score 2):

For mac:

To collapse all methods: `'Cmd' + 'Shift' + '-'`

To expand all methods: `'Cmd' + 'Shift' + '+'`